# Service Syncronize doesn't work on API => level 26

Tags: android, synchronization, android-service

I've some services, that it wasn't working on Android from level 26 and above. 
They are activated, as you can see in this image from User & Account Settings:

[image]

Even if I restart this synchronization, the service doesn't execute on app. But they are working fine in older Android API versions.

**Android Manifest.xml**:

*uses-permission*

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
```

*application*

***providers***

```
    <provider
        android:name=".sincronismo.SincronizadorSemFilaContentProvider"
        android:authorities="@string/sincronismo_sem_fila_content_authority"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/sincronismo_sem_fila_rotulo"
        android:syncable="true" />
    <provider
        android:name=".sincronismo.SincronizadorComFilaContentProvider"
        android:authorities="@string/sincronismo_com_fila_content_authority"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/sincronismo_com_fila_rotulo"
        android:syncable="true" />
```

***services***

```
    <service
        android:name=".sincronismo.SincronizadorSemFilaService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/sincronismo_sem_fila_sync_adapter" />
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".sincronismo.SincronizadorComFilaService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/sincronismo_com_fila_sync_adapter" />
    </service>
```

**SincronizadorComFilaService** a few differences to **SincronizadorSemFilaService**, but basically the same:

```
public class SincronizadorComFilaService extends Service {
private static final Object SYNC_ADAPTER_LOCK = new Object();
private static AbstractSincronizadorAdapter syncAdapter;

public SincronizadorComFilaService() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    synchronized (SYNC_ADAPTER_LOCK) {
        if (syncAdapter == null){
            syncAdapter = new AbstractSincronizadorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true) {
                @Override
                protected void executarSincronismo(ServicoFactory servicoFactory,
                        Account account, Bundle extras, String authority,
                        ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult)
                        throws AbstractServicoException {
                    servicoFactory.getSincronismoService().executarSincronismoComFila();
                }
            };
        }
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return syncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
}
}
```

**sincronismo_com_fila_sync_adapter.xml** again, with a few differences to **sincronismo_sem_fila_sync_adapter**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:contentAuthority="@string/sincronismo_com_fila_content_authority"
android:accountType="@string/seguranca_tipo_conta"
android:supportsUploading="true"
android:userVisible="true"
android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its posible that you need run into a JobService, becouse service in not now the good solution.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService

Answer (score 0):

Android has restricted Background Services from API Level 26. [Read here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). But there are some alternatives of Service. You have to switch you work to the latest [**Work Manager API**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics).

You can also try [**Job Scheduler**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) which works from API 21. Another alternative is [**Firebase Dispatcher**](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android). It works from API 14.

All of these three can survive the System boot operation or Network constraints. Service is not really a good solution for your synchronizations.